# Electron and edge.js using .NET core DLL gives errors

Tags: .net-core, electron, edge.js

After days of trying and googling i decided to try and find a solution here.

The project uses electron-edge-js with electron and angular for UI.

I built a netcoreapp2.0 dll - very basic:

```
namespace ParserLibrary
{
    public class Parser
    {
        public string GetText()
        {
            return "test";
        }
    }
}
```

Used like this:

```
var getCurrentTime = edge.func({
    source: function() {/*
    using System;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using ParserLibrary;

    public class Startup
    {      
        public Parser parser = new Parser();
        public async Task<object> Invoke(object input)
        {
            return parser.GetText();
        }
    }
*/},
    references: [path.join(__dirname, "DataParser.dll")]
});
```

But this is the error i end up with when i run electron

```
"Unable to compile C# code.
----> Errors when compiling as a CLR library:
c:\Users\**\AppData\Local\Temp\xwlkiee0.0.cs(8,16) : error CS0012: The type 'System.Object' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.
----> Errors when compiling as a CLR async lambda expression:
c:\Users\**\AppData\Local\Temp\rf0qpqan.0.cs(5,42) : error CS1513: } expected
c:\Users\**\AppData\Local\Temp\rf0qpqan.0.cs(20,9) : error CS1519: Invalid token 'return' in class, struct, or interface member declaration
c:\Users\**\AppData\Local\Temp\rf0qpqan.0.cs(20,35) : error CS1001: Identifier expected
c:\Users\**\AppData\Local\Temp\rf0qpqan.0.cs(22,1) : error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected
c:\Users\**\AppData\Local\Temp\rf0qpqan.0.cs(10,18) : error CS0542: 'Startup': member names cannot be the same as their enclosing type"
```

It runs fine if i comment out the Parser related lines.
What am i missing here - or edge doesn't really support use of custom dll like that?

Comment: As far as i know edge pulls the dll from the package.json outgoing. If you move the  into your root folder and then do a `references: [ 'DataParser.dll' ]` it should work ;) When you build the electron for release you have to use `app.getAppPath()` as a base.

Comment: The dll was in the same folder with the main node js

Comment: But did you change your code according to my suggestion? Also your node.js entry file could be located anywhere, important is your package.json since it is your application path.

Comment: have you solved the issue ? I am kinda stuck to a similar issue, would be nice if you could provide an answer :) tnx in advance

Comment: @bnxuq Can't fully remember anymore - I end up giving up on the .net integration and user node with binaryjs to read/parse files.

I think you had to have the whole Startup with Task<object> Invoke(object input) in the DLL - so you have to build special DLL just for the edge and couldn't use common/shared ones.